# Cron job to delay a form post

Tags: php, html, forms, cron

So say I have a form like this:

```
<form target="_blank" action="submit.php" method="post">
what it should say:<input name="info" type="text" />
<br /><br />
When (24hour.day.month.year)<input placeholder="24.13.04.95" name="date" type="text" /><br /><br />
<input name="" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Where you type what you want it to say. And choose the date at which the form posts†.

†So that when you submit the form it creates a cron job of the post to the `submit.php` page which send an email with what it should say at the time that is inputed.

like this:

```
$message = $_POST['info'];
mail('example@hotmail.com', 'Subject', $message);
```

Is this possible? And is this right way to go about delaying a form post for a substantial amount of time?

Comment: You need to store the data somewhere else, `$_POST` will not be available. A database with the message & the time it should be sent seems most apt.

Comment: I don't think it's right to create a cron job for every submits unless you really really need the messages to be sent up to the exact second... If not, simply just store the submitted data in a database along with the timestamp of when the message should be sent (and trigger a "checker" every hour)

Comment: so put the data into a temporary database and then post from that at a certain time? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Grab the data, then do the "real" post.

Comment: @rlatief: ah, indeed, missed that. Just have the one cronjob (or, if you want to make them several jobs, don't use cron- but atjobs).

Comment: any tutorials you know of?

Comment: I want it to work like facebook does where you can Create a "schedule" type thing. Are there any other methods? I know of `sleep()` for php but that is for short amount of times. I am looking at storing the post a month in advance

Comment: see my answer below might help you to get started :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to "edit" your logic.

You can do a POST programmatically, but it's not needed in your case.

Pseudo:

```
1. User submit the form

2. Save data to database, along with a timestamp:

    $stamp = time() + ( 3600 * 24 * 30 );
    // $stamp is 30 days in the future

3. Create a cron job to run hourly, to trigger the sender code:

    1. Select from database where timestamp is less than current time()
    2. If row(s) found, send the mail. No POST involved
    3. Delete rows from database
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to store $_POST data and schedule a single cron every minute that check if there are messages to send.

Comment: care to make your answer better with actual code on how to do this?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: why? This is a perfectly correct answer.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier my answer is laconic but contains THE solution of this XY problem :-P